# Shell theorem in general Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry

How is it that gravitational field inside a spherically symmetric body is zero in case of General Relativity where the equations are nonlinear unlike Newtonian gravity where the force is perfectly $1/r^2$.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43626/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219897/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Also in newtonian gravity equations are non linear, so I would not raise that argument.