# Gravitational pull of the earth

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth, planets

Where is the gravitational force actually present in earth? In air, in soil or is it in the deep core of earth? Well, the core seems the most probable answer out of the three. But then, gravity in core is - ZERO. Then, where does the gravitational pull originate from?

Comment: Everything that has a mass produces gravitational force. Just take your position and mass, sum over all contributions of other masses on you, and you will get the pull.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18446/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the gravitational force actually present in earth? In air, in soil or is it in the deep core of earth?

Yes, yes and yes. Every particle with mass - every atom in air and ground - exerts a gravitational force on everything else that has mass. This statement is from [Newton's law of gravitation](https://www.google.dk/search?q=newton%27s%20law%20of%20gravitation&oq=newtons%20law%20of%20graviational&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3330j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

So you cannot say that gravity originates at some specific location only. You could average it if you have to and imagine all gravitational force pulling from the centre and causing a pull in the centre of other things. Because the mass can be "averaged" down to one point (called the [centre of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass)). But that is just an average made in order to have a simplified model.

- If you are standing on the Earth, you are being pulled in by all particles that the Earth and the atmosphere are made of. The net force is straight downwards.
- If you are standing in the very core of Earth, the gravitational force on you by each particle in Earth is **not zero**. But it all cancels out because you have equally many particles on either side (assuming perfectly spherical Earth). You are definitely being pulled in leftwards but also equally much rightwards.

The **net** gravitational force on you is zero in Earth's centre, but not because no gravitational force is exerted on you. It just happens to cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity comes from everything. I have gravity you have gravity, so basically its present everywhere. Gravity originates from all the atoms the earth is made up of but it pulls us towards the center of mass which is the core. The reason there is little gravity in the core, is because all the mass around you is pulling at you when your in the center. I hope that answers your question.

Sources

NASA, NASA, helios.gsfc.nasa.gov/qa_gp_gr.html.

Comment: Gravity is non-zero at the core, because the Earth is not a perfect sphere, nor is the mass distribution uniform.

Comment: @JamalS Is there *any* point within the Earth where gravity *is* zero?

Answer (score 0):

Every particle which has mass, has gravity and every *body* which made up some particles has gravity. The earth made with many/much particles and their gravity sum together to make gravity at whole. Gravity make field and around every mass we have gravitational field. Earth core is in gravitational field and we are in that field there.