# What is the gravity at the center of the Earth?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, earth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would you be weightless at the center of the Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/would-you-be-weightless-at-the-center-of-the-earth)

Supposing there is a cavity at the center of the Earth, what is the gravity there? What will be its direction and intensity? Will a body be attracted toward the center of mass of the Earth?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2481/2451

Comment: 'bout zero in the middle

Answer (score 0):

The gravitational field a distance $r$ from the center of a solid sphere with uniformly distributed mass is
$$
g\left(r\right) = -\left(\frac{4}{3} \pi G \rho \right) r,
$$
where $\rho$ is the mass density of the sphere, and $G$ is the gravitational constant. The value of the field at the center is
$$
g\left(0\right) = 0.
$$
The actual field at the center of the Earth will not be zero, however, because the Earth is not a perfect sphere, does not have uniform density, and is not the only object in the universe.