# What the effect of gravity in the center of a planet feels like

Tags: gravity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would you be weightless at the center of the Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/would-you-be-weightless-at-the-center-of-the-earth)

The issue of weightlessness at the center of the Earth has obviously already been discussed, however I am curious as to know what will it feel like as a human.

Will it be absolute weightlessness as experienced by being in space, or will the mass of the Earth surrounding you pull you apart in all directions in a free floating expansion with your eyeballs popping out, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you feel nothing like you are in space. Even if you are accelerating, you are still feel nothing as long as the gravitational field is sufficiently uniform over your whole body. Then each part of your body are accelerating at the same rate, and your neuron wont complain it to your brain.

The gravitational field generated by the Earth is weak and very uniform over a short range, say 1m. Particular, at the center of Earth, the gravity is almost uniform so that you cannot feel anything and certainly wont pull you apart. You may be driven toward a particular direction until you hit an object, then you feel reaction from that object. (I am assuming you can make a spherical hole at the center of Earth, and there is no air hitting your face)