# Does gravity change the closer you are to the Earth's core?

Tags: gravity, acceleration, earth

Very simple question that has bugged me for some time, does the acceleration produced by gravitation (e.g. $9.8\: \mathrm{m/s^2}$) would change if we placed an observer closer to the planet's core? I mean, if I were to sit on the center of the Earth, would I still feel the Earth's gravitational field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2481/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18446/

Comment: Obviously no, at earth's core what should be the direction of gravity?