# What would happen if the Earth were hollow?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

This is a question of my exam. What would a person experienced if he were put in any point inside the Earth that is hollow (all its mass is concentrated in the surface). Finding the gravitational field intensity, it turns out to be 0. I interpret it as if the person didn't experience any acceleration; as a result, He should stand still there where he was put in.

That's what I get to conclude. But, what do you think?

Comment: The gravity exerted by any part of the sphere on a mass inside of it would be cancelled by the gravity exerted by an opposite part of the sphere.  Here is an explanation of how to prove it: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/sphshell2.html

Comment: See [Newton's shell theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem). Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150238/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

It means that he might as well be in outer space. He will float weightless in the air. If he jumps toward the center of the earth he will gradually slow down and stop due to air friction, and will then be trapped, unable to move in any direction. Unless he drank a lot of fluids before he jumped.