# Trouble with geometric proof of gravitational force inside a sphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, symmetry

In [Newton's superb theorem: An elementary geometric proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6534) (Argument on Page 4, accompanying diagram on Page 11), the author attempts to prove Proposition 70 in Newton's Principia (gravitational force = 0 inside a hollow sphere) with a more streamlined version of Newton's original argument.

But the problem is I don't understand why we need to use infinitesimal cones instead of normal ones, since the area on the sphere formed by the cone can be calculated from $r^2\theta$, where $\theta$ is the solid angle of the cone's vertex, shouldn't the conclusion just fall out?

If, however, I resort to infinitesimal cones, why should the elemental area $dS$ be $\frac{r^2d\Omega}{\cos \alpha}$? Where does $\cos\alpha$ come from, and why does it matter that the angle between the normal to the surface and the cone be equal on both sides?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150238/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic, I have looked at the post before writing this, but the link which explains the geometry behind the problem is only accessible to registered users with an institution ID. My trouble is with the geometry of the area formed by the intersection of the cone (with a solid angle) and the surface of the hollow sphere, specifically, why the angle between the normal to the sphere and the cone matters.