# Gravitational field due to inner shell on the outer shell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity

There're two uniform hollow shells of radius $R$ and $2R$ each. The one with radius $R$ is inside the larger shell touching the larger shell's inner surface and its center. What's the net gravitational force on
(i)surface of smaller sphere.
(ii)region between smaller and larger sphere.
(iii)surface of larger sphere.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Are you asking about the net force between the two shells? If so this is a variant of the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem).

Comment: Gravitational force on the outer shell due to the presence of inner shell

Comment: yes, but they're the same

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150238/2451 and links therein.

Comment: do you search for the field inside the outer shell or at its surface ? anyway, interesting results but trivial solution. In the question, replace **why** by **what**

Comment: @igael I did. Now please do answer. I'm just not getting this.

Comment: @AnubhabDas : ok. Are the spheres the same density ? Are the shells densities different than inside the spheres ? with the same density , it is equivalent to one sphere only , solvable by the shell theorem

Comment: They're of same density.  Still, how to solve?

Comment: if they have the same density, you may ignore the 2nd sphere inside , it is just virtual ( in a gravity exercise ). Then apply the shell theorem with the 1st sphere. With different densities, you may start with the shell theorem for the 1st sphere and add the 2nd sphere with the difference of densities ( or reverse if the 2nd density if lower )