# Electric field in a spherical shell

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry, charge, gauss-law

Question mentioned like this find out the electric field inside and outside a spherical shell of radius r which carries a uniform surface charge density sigma.

In the above question it is not mentioned that the shell is conductive or non conductive than how one can attempt  this question and what assumption required for it.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150238/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Since the charge density is stated to be uniform, whether the shell is conductive (which guarantees the uniform distribution for a sphere) or not doesn't matter.