# Please explain the given statement

Tags: newtonian-gravity, symmetry, gauss-law

There is a statement in my physics textbook in gravitation chapter -
The force of attraction due to hollow spherical shell of uniform density on a point mass situated inside it is zero
Is it valid for solid sphere? What happens in solid sphere? Please explain this statement.

Comment: This is called the shell theorem. You can analyze a solid ball as a collection of concentric shells.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150238/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Closely related question by OP:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/493993/what-do-you-mean-by-the-given-statement

Comment: The same question as before...