# How to prove gravitational force inside a hollow sphere is zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

I'm just trying to prove that gravitational force on an object within a hollow sphere is zero when these are the only two objects under consideration within the system.

I know some multivariable calculus, I just want someone to walk me through the integration deriving the mass element dM and the integration of thin rings composing the hollow sphere. It would also be nice if you could show me doing it one way using the solid angle and one way without using the solid angle. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gravitational field intensity inside a hollow sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150238/gravitational-field-intensity-inside-a-hollow-sphere)

Comment: It’s easier to do the integral for the gravitational *potential* and show that it is uniform inside. This means that the field (the gradient of the potential) is zero.

Comment: @G.Smith I see. I would have to find the potential function.

Comment: Related : [Would you be weightless at the center of the Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/would-you-be-weightless-at-the-center-of-the-earth).