# Difference between the softening parameter in a Plummer model of a star cluster vs. the softening parameter in a softened gravitational potential

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, many-body, star-clusters

I am doing a gravitational N-body simulation of a star cluster. I set up my initial conditions using the Plummer model, which has potential
$$\Phi_P = -\frac{G M}{\sqrt{r^2 + a^2}},\tag{1}$$
where $M$ is the total cluster mass, and $a$ is a parameter which I have seen explained in 2 different ways: some sources describe it as a scaling parameter for the size of the cluster, whereas other sources motivate the inclusion of $a$ as a numerical trick to prevent divergence of the gravitational potential at small separations.

For the force between stars, I am using a softened gravitational potential
$$\Phi_G = -\frac{G m_1 m_2}{\sqrt{r^2 + \epsilon^2}},\tag{2}$$
where $\epsilon$ is motivated as a numerical trick for preventing divergence of the gravitational potential at small separations (note the similarity with the second definition of $a$).

My question boils down to this: should $a$ and $\epsilon$ have the same value? In case the answer is context dependent, I am interested in the studying the relaxation time of clusters with fewer than 1000 stars.

So far, I have been treating them as different values, because I understand $a$ as just specifying the size of the system and $\epsilon$ as something I needed to set appropriately in order to suppress close encounters that lead to the ejection of stars via unphysically large forces. A problem with this is that when I generate the Plummer model, it is meant to be born in Virial equilibrium, but if I then use a softened form of gravity, this modifies the potential (without modifying the kinetic energy), so that the system is not in fact in Virial equilibrium. Also, I am finding it difficult to decide on an appropriate value of $\epsilon$, and thought that perhaps the appropriate value is $a$ since the second explanation given for $a$ is identical to the explanation of $\epsilon$.

Comment: I have never seen $a$ described as a numerical trick, only as the scale of the system (for instance, [Flynn et al 1996](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1996MNRAS.281.1027F/abstract) uses $a\sim3$ kpc for the bulge/stellar halo scale parameter). Can you provide a reference that indicates $a$ is a numerical trick?

Comment: Thinking about it some, I imagine that the usage of "numerical trick" is in context of the latter potential you write (i.e., stellar potentials, not galactic potential in the classic usage of "Plummer model"). I know it's reasonably standard practice, but I would be wary of using $\epsilon$ values in the denominator, as it is possible to provide incorrect results (e.g., convergence is to a 'wrong' value); it'd be better to create a linearized model for small $r$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @KyleKanos. A reference referring to $a$ as softening in the context of Plummer's model can be found in section 1.3 of [this]( https://web.archive.org/web/20190727214232/http://www.artcompsci.org/kali/vol/plummer/volume11.pdf) book chapter. Please could you elaborate on what you mean by making a linearised model?

Comment: Basically at small $r$, the density of the object plays a role. If you assume a constant density, then you can actually find that $F\propto r$ which you can then infer a gravitational potential. See [Trimok's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/68570/25301) for more details.

Comment: But for $n$-body simulations, I imagine a collision/bounce/merger/obliteration would be preferred to artificially inserting $\epsilon$ into the denominator.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I will consider implementing those alternatives, although I am finding today that for my experiments, I can easily make $\epsilon$ and the timestep small enough that the Plummer sphere is generated in approximate Virial equilibrium and that if $\epsilon$ is not too large, it doesn't have very much effect on the relaxation timescale (which makes some physical sense).