# Detection limits on 'd' if gravity force was proportional to $1 / (R+d)^2$

Tags: gravity

Assume the force of gravity is proportional to $1/(R+d)^2$ where $d$ is sufficiently small,

then, how small would $d$ have to be to evade detection by modern experiments?

My thinking is that if $d$ is not zero then it would solve the issue of a singularity when $R$ is 0.

Comment: Did you look for papers containing "Non-Newtonian gravity" and "compact extra dimensions"? I think you will find a treasure trove of both experimental and theoretical work.

Answer (score 4):

I answered a related question in [this earlier answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/216284/26969) where I pointed to a [1988 experiment/paper by Mitrofanov et al](http://jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_067_10_1963.pdf), where they determined that any deviation from the inverse square law must happen at length scale < 1 mm.

Note that the assumption of their paper was a different form of the potential function -

$$V(r) = -G_\infty\frac{M}{r}\left(1+\alpha e^{-r/r_0}\right)$$

But the basic length scale will be comparable.