# Gravitiation force of a sphere

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity

Was wondering about Shell Theorem, specifically about the immediate results.

- Force (on a point mass) inside a shell is 0.
- Force (on a point mass) outside a shell is GmM/r^2

From what i know the force from a similar scenario but with a solid sphere (outisde) is the same right? What is the result of the Force inside for a solid sphere? Still 0?

thanks

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2481/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a solid sphere of mass $M$ and radius $R$ and a smaller mass $m$ at a distance $r<R$ from the centre.

Note that a solid sphere is equal to a smaller solid sphere of radius $r$ plus an outer shell:

[image]

The force from the outer shell is zero, and the force from the inner sphere is 
$$ Gm\left(M\frac{r^3}{R^3}\right) \frac{1}{r^2}$$

Comment: okay, how did you go about determining the formula for the inner sphere?

Comment: @Jesse It's the same formula you gave in your question except I've replaced $M$ with $Mr^3/R^3$ which is the mass within a radius $r$.