# Gravitational field strength inside the Earth

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth

please could someone give me a relatively straight forward answer why the gravitational field strength follows a straight line (linear) relationship with distance from the center of the Earth but when you get to the surface it follows a 1/r^2 relationship?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18446/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2481/2451 and links therein.

Comment: See the linked questions. Use Gauss's law.

Comment: Just to round it up: the linear dependence of gravity on radius is a consequence of the model assumption that the density of the planet is constant. In reality, however, the density of the material increases greatly.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone give me a relatively straight forward answer why the gravitational field strength follows a straight line (linear) relationship with distance from the center of the Earth but when you get to the surface it follows a 1/r^2 relationship?

Basically, it doesn't.

A better model is that gravitation is more or less constant at 10 m/s<sup>2</sup> to halfway down toward the center of the Earth, and then drops linearly toward zero at the from that point inward.

An even better model is the Preliminary reference Earth model, [Dziewonski and Anderson, "Preliminary reference Earth model," *Physics of the Earth and Planetary Interiors* 25.4 (1981): 297-356](http://web.gps.caltech.edu/classes/ge102/papers/PREM_1981.pdf). This 30 year old model of the Earth's interior gives a good view of the interior of the Earth. The tabular data that go into the model are freely available at http://geophysics.ou.edu/solid_earth/prem.html.

A planet with a uniform density would exhibit a gravitational force that falls linearly toward zero at the center. The problem is that the Earth doesn't have anything close to a uniform density. It has a very dense iron/nickel core surrounded by a rather dense rock (the mantle), which in turn supports the relatively light crust.

Answer (score 0):

In spherical symmetry, the gravitational force only depends on the mass inside of a sphere of radius r, in an image where you pretend it was concentrated in the center.

The gravitational force falls off as $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$, always.  When you are inside the sphere, though (if you assume constant density) then the mass included increases by a factor of $r^{3}$, so you pick up more mass a factor of $r$ more quickly than the force falls off.