# Does the "center" of the gravitational field change as we approach the center of the mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets

I've learned that the gravitational force is a vector going from the body inside the gravitational field towards the center of the mass that creates the field.
The intensity of the force depends on the body's mass, evidently.

However, if gravitational fields are created when there's mass, why if we approached the center of a planet and went inside (supposing we could), we wouldn't feel gravitational pull from the surrounding mass, but still be attracted towards the center.

Supposedly, when you reach the center of a planet, there is no more mass in the center, and you should be attracted to the mass surrounding you.

Why does the gravity vector always go towards the center of the mass, regardless of the distance between the bodies?

I've just started to address the Kepler Laws and the universal gravitational law for the first time. First time posting here, as well.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18446/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2481/2451 and links therein.

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/earthole.html . also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity#Spherically_symmetric_mass_distribution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does gravity work underground?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18446/)