# Let's say you are at the center of the earth witch way would gravity pull?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth

which way would gravity pull at the center of the earth

Comment: It won't pull at all (assuming all the mass is symmetrically distributed above you). Hint, work out the equations yourself and see.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2481/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no way. Because "pull" means an unbalanced force on an object, and there's no unbalanced force in the center of earth